# save excel worksheet in shared not protected read only mode from C#

Tags: c#, excel

I am saving a worksheet created in C# using Workbook.SaveAs method. The XlSaveAsAccessMode argument is giving me issues.

xlShared saves worksheet in protected mode so users cannot play around with charts and examine them carefully. It basically shows as a dead chart which cannot be referenced to data.

xlExclusive allows the user saving the book unprotected access but not others. The other users still see a dead chart.

I need to save the worksheet in a mode that allows everyone to view and examine it and be able to play around with charts, connect the series with data points, etc. But at the same time, they should not be able to save their changes to overwrite the file. How do I achieve this using C# COM Excel API?

References -

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.saveas(v=vs.80).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlsaveasaccessmode.aspx

Answer (score 5):

First save your file using a password against modifications - you can do this in the *Save As* dialog (under the *Tools* dropdown on the bottom of the dialog) as you save out your file. Also check the *Read-only recommended* checkbox to force read-only mode on the file.

When users open the file, Excel will ask for the write password but users who don't have that password will be forced to go to read-only mode. In read-only mdoe, users can make any changes to the file but they can't save over the original file (regardless of the read-only attribute in the file system) - they can only save a new copy of the file under a new name (or the same name in a different folder).

To programmatically save your workbook with these properties, you can do something like:

```
oWorkbook.SaveAs ( oWorkbook.Path + @"\Workbook.xls",
    Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault,
    missing,
    "WritePassword",  // password against modification
    true,             // read-only recommended
    false,
    Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
    missing,
    missing,
    missing,
    missing,
    missing );
```

You can also handle the [`WorkBookBeforeSave`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.appevents_event.workbookbeforesave%28v=office.14%29.aspx) event and update the workbook with tracking information to identify copies of your original workbook. This would help with copies saved under the original file name in a different folder. (I'm not familiar with this particular event but you may even be able to cancel the save operation when handling it.)

Unless you fully control the file (which is near impossible using only Excel) users will be able to make copies of your file but the above settings at least force them to save new copies while the original is intact. Does this solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks for the information. Can you give an example of WorkBook.SaveAs call that you would make to achieve these objectives - that is allow everyone read-only but unprotected access to the file? I need to do this programatic-ally as this is part of a daily reporting process. I don't what value to set for XlSaveAsAccessMode  to enable unprotected access for others. It seems all values of XlSaveAsAccessMode lock the worksheet for other users besides me.

Comment: @user236215 I updated my answer with an example - this should save your workbook with the right settings. Before implementing this, try it out on a normal workbook that you just create in Excel (not programmatically) to see how it'll work for users. I think this does what you need.

Comment: Thanks. I really appreciate your help. I am going to try this tomorrow morning and will inform you how it went. I have another related question. I am creating my files from a template-file. Currently the template has write access. I open a new file using the template. make changes and save as my report. Now, if I make the template read-only, does that impact my flow in any way? I am going to test this tomorrow as well. Basically, I want to make the template read-only, protected and locked, so no one but me can modify it.

Comment: @user236215 Don't make your template read-only - simply open it, generate your report and then use the above `SaveAs` call to save it as read-only. I assume your users have no access to the template you use (or if they do it's of no use to them) so there's no need to have it read-only.

Comment: Yes, users can't see it. But I don't want my team members to change it unintentionally, as that will mess up the reporting. Ideally, it should allow me to use the template to create a new report as long as I have read access on it right?

Comment: @user236215 Yes, as long as you can open the file, you should be fine. You can also save your template with a write password from Excel - when you open it programmatically, you'll have to supply the password and then you can go about your business.